# sharp increase and sharp decrease?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, vocabulary

According to the [following figure](http://0up.ir/do.php?imgf=ggggg.jpg), is usage of  "sharp increase and sharp decrease" correct? If it is not , please suggest ways to make it clearer.

Sentences:

> As the value of K decreases from 0.16 to 0.105, the sharp increase in the value of G and the sharp decrease in the value of D could be due to the high effect of interaction between the wake of upstream blade and the boundary layer on the suction surface of the blade as expressed previously.

In other words, I want to explain that there is a high effect of an interaction in low values of K. In fact, low values of k caused the high effect of interaction. And also, this high effect makes that parameter of D decrease and parameter of G increase with decreasing in the value of K=0.16 to 0.105. my intention is to describe interaction, rather than describe the graph. I don't want to explain graph features (slope).

Answer (score 2):

The word 'sharp' is used if the increase or decrease is sudden. There must be a peak in the graph to call it 'sharp'. The curve for D(the green one) is more or less a smooth one. The curve for D is also smooth in the range K=0.105-0.16.

[image]

The part of the Euribor curve that reaches a value slightly more than 200 in this graph may be called as a 'sharp increase'.

In my opinion, *As the value of K decreases from 0.16 to 0.105, the **large** increase in the value of G and the **large** decrease in the value of D could be due to the high effect of interaction between the wake of upstream blade and the boundary layer on the suction surface of the blade as expressed previously.* would be better.